# Blade view: if statement with OR/AND condition

Tags: php, if-statement, view, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Is it possible in **Laravel 4.0** -blade-view to do an if statment like so?

```
@if ($var1 === '1' OR $var2 === '1')
    //Do my stuff
@endif
```

Or

```
@if ($var1 === '1' || $var2 === '1')
    //Do my stuff
@endif
```

Or whatever syntax it is. I didn't find anything in the L4 docs, does it exist ?

Comment: Have you tried out your code and it doesn't work?

Comment: PHP does not have a 4-equals operator. Did you mean `===`?

Comment: Sry typo with ====. To be clear. a simple @if is working perfectly, so it's not the condition itself

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It should support all of your standard PHP operators, including || (logical OR).

I have tested it myself and it works fine.

Additionally, I would recommend simply testing this yourself in future to confirm it works/doesn't work.

Comment: I tested it before coming in here, but you're right. The problem must be elsewhere...

Comment: @pc-shooter so what is the actual problem? Any error message?

Comment: `@if(Session::has('user_handle') && Session::get('user_handle') == $angular_to_handle1)` here '&&' not working for me. i am using laravel 5.2

Answer (score 15):

You can simply use `and` / `or` operators:

```
@if($a==1 and $b==2)
@if($a==1 or $b==2)
```