# '&&' for AND clause sign for blade template laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have my code here

```
@if(Auth::user()->nbi_clearance_image == null &&  Auth::user()->medical_certificate_image == null)
```

but the `&&` is not working in blade templates. any ideas how to do `AND` clauses in blade?

Comment: Strange problem `&&` should work. I think you have other problem in your code than `&&`

Comment: Share `Auth::user()` ?

Comment: What makes you think it is not working?

Comment: what do you expect? what do you have? this will help to give a specific answer without simply just suggesting different opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wrapping each statement in brackets?

```
@if((Auth::user()->nbi_clearance_image == null) && (Auth::user()->medical_certificate_image == null))
```

You also should be able to do a double comparison.

```
@if(Auth::user()->nbi_clearance_image == Auth::user()->medical_certificate_image == null)
```

Comment: the && sign is highlighted and i dont know why

Answer (score 0):

According to some of the comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20841039/blade-view-if-statement-with-or-and-condition), the && doesn't seem to work for others either.

As inconvenient as it is, you may have to use nested @if statements to work around this.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@if((Auth::user()->nbi_clearance_image == null)
    && (Auth::user()->medical_certificate_image == null))
```

you can try this

Answer (score 0):

You should try this, it works for me:

```
@if(Auth::user()->nbi_clearance_image == '' &&  Auth::user()->medical_certificate_image == '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(!Auth::user()->nbi_clearance_image && !Auth::user()->medical_certificate_image) 
        //code
@endif
```

If this don't work then your problem is not with &&.

Answer (score 0):

Opertor && has been removed from laravel version 5.7